# Why won't this bash function work the same as when running directly?

Tags: bash, sed, find

I wrote a function in `/etc/bashrc` as I was using it quite often, but now it doesn't seem to work:

```
function replaceall() {
  find "$1" -type f -exec sed -i "s|$2|$3|g" {} \;
}
```

When running it directly I'd do something like:

```
find ./*/conf/production/*.conf -type f -exec sed -i "s|/home/user/sites|/var/www/vhosts|g" {} \;
```

Which works fine. But when calling with the `replaceall` function it doesn't work:

```
replaceall ./*/conf/production/*.conf "/home/user/sites" "/var/www/vhosts"
```

**Note:** It does work when I use `replaceall . [...]` so that makes me wonder, **am I missing some crucial syntax?**

Comment: You're missing some double quotes around `"$1"`, for a start.

Comment: Thanks @TomFenech, I've done that and updated my question.

Comment: Note `./*/conf/production/*.conf` will get expanded, so probably `$2` contains one of these expansions. Debug by saying `echo find ...` and see what really gets there.

Comment: Aha! @fedorqui yes, it echo'd just one line, and `$1`, `$2` and `$3` were the first three files found respectively. I called it with quotes (`replaceall "./*/..." ...` but that just says file not found. Is there a way to achieve both?

Comment: Are you sure you definitely need to use `find` at all? If so, you should probably be using `-name '*.conf'`, combined with `-prune` to skip paths that don't contain `conf/production` (though I'm not sure of the exact syntax off the top of my head...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're relying on the traversal capability of `find` at all, so I'd suggest that you just used glob expansion with a loop:

```
replaceall() {
    for file in $1; do
        sed -i.bak "s|$2|$3|g" "$file"
    done
}
```

Then call the script, quoting each argument:

```
replaceall "./*/conf/production/*.conf" "/home/user/sites" "/var/www/vhosts"
```

Quoting each argument ensures that the expansion of the path takes place within the function. I've also added a suffix to the `-i` switch so a backup is made of each file that is affected, otherwise your script is pretty dangerous!

As mentioned in the comments, there is still a potential issue with this approach. If you want to pass a path containing spaces, then these will have to escaped to protect against word splitting. For example, a path like `"./*/conf/production files/*.conf"` requires a backslash in front of the space `"./*/conf/production\ files/*.conf"`.

Comment: One caveat: word splitting occurs before pathname expansion, though, so this won't work with a first argument like `"./*/conf/production files/*.conf"`. You'd have to escape any spaces: `".../production\ files/*.conf"`.

Comment: @chepner thanks, I updated my answer to mention that.

Comment: Thanks @TomFenech, this seems like the most sensible way to do it, at least until I require extra functionality `that find` can provide. P.S sorry for spelling your name incorrectly above! ;)

Comment: @Leonard no worries - I removed the edit summary anyway as it wouldn't be relevant to future readers. It's far from the worst spelling of my name by the way!

Answer (score 1):

I would write it as below:

```
function replaceall() {
  local search=$1
  local replace=$2
  shift 2
  for i in "$@"
      find "$i" -type f -exec sed -i "s|$search|$replace|g" {} \;
  done
}

replaceall "/home/user/sites" "/var/www/vhosts" ./*/conf/production/*.conf
```